# YouCompleteMe cannot complete C function with parameters

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

I have set this `let g:ycm_key_invoke_completion = "<c-q>"`, and then I can see the pop menu without parameters.

If I press Ctrl+q, the pop menu is the same one.

How can it complete a global function with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like issues [294](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/234) and [1193](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1193) on GitHub.

> Valloric commented on Nov 18, 2014:
>
> This is on my TODO list, but I mostly don't have time for a large-scale feature like this. Sometimes I find some of it, but it's rare (every few months).